# Cannot read property 'post' of undefined angular factory

Tags: angularjs, controller, jwt, factory

I am stuck on one problem, i use angular and got controller for send data into my factory where i have method which have to post username, login etc to my end point where i generate JWT for further use, but somehow i get this error and dont know why it even happens.

Any idea what may cause this problem?

TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at Object.login (Auth.js:22)
    at Scope.LoginController.$scope.signIn (LoginController.js:11)

here is my factory for post request to my end point

```
'use strict';
angular.module("Diplomka").factory('oauth', [function oauth($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        login: function (username, password) {
            var token = "";
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                }
            }

            var data = {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                grant_type: "password"
            }

            $http.post("/Token", data, config)
                .then(function (response) {
                    token = response.access_token;
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

here is my controller

```
    'use strict';
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', 'oauth', '$location', LoginController]);
function LoginController($scope, oauth, $location) {


    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";

    $scope.signIn = function () {
        oauth.login($scope.username, $scope.password);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your "array syntax" wrong. There is a mismatch between your service names and the variables you are passing as a parameter to your factory constructor function.

```
'use strict';
angular.module("Diplomka").factory('oauth', ['$rootScope', '$http', function oauth($scope, $http) { // It should be like this
    // Rest of your factory here
}]);
```

Also, I don't think it's a good idea to inject `$rootScope` to your factory using the variable name `$scope`. Instead I would call it also `$rootScope` and replace all `$scope` references in your factory.

```
'use strict';
angular.module("Diplomka").factory('oauth', ['$rootScope', '$http', function oauth($rootScope, $http) { // It should be like this
    // Rest of your factory here, replacing $scope with $rootScope
}]);
```

Comment: oh what a stupid mistake i made there, thanks a lot, its working now